# Update em todos os registros da coleção no MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Criei um campo nova na minha coleção, mas gostaria de incluir esse campo novo em todos os registros da minha coleção.

Tentei usar o script dessa forma:

```
db.getCollection('Contratos').update(
  {},
  {$set: {'pendente': false} },
  false,
  true
)
```

Mas me retorna o seguinte erro por conter muitos registros na coleção.

> Request rate is large. More Request Units may be needed, so no changes were made. Please retry this request later.

Existe alguma maneira de contornar esta situação sem precisar executar o mesmo update mais de uma vez?

Comment: Chegou a tentar usando `updateMany`? esses `false` e `true` é o mesmo que `{upsert: false,  multi: true}`?

Comment: Acabei de tentar o `updateMany` e retornou o mesmo erro. Sobre os parâmetros, sim.. É o `upsert: false` e `multi: true`.